# Why aren't these numpy operations equivalent, and how can I fix that?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following arrays:

```
X = np.array([[1, 27, 3], [4, -1, 6]])
W = np.array([2, 4, 3])
```

These two equations are equivalent:

```
sum_a = 0
for l in range(len(X)):
    sum_a += np.sum(W * X[l])   # 141
sum_b = np.sum(np.sum(W * X))   # 141
```

But these two are not:

```
sum_a = 0
for l in range(len(X)):
    sum_a += np.exp(np.sum(W * X[l]))   # 4.797813327299302e+51
sum_b = np.sum(np.exp(np.sum(W * X)))   # 1.7199742630376623e+61
```

Why is that, and how can I make sum_b equivalent to sum_a for the second case? I specifically want to equate the sum using numpy so I can vectorize a bigger equation.

Comment: Show the `sum_a` etc along with the code

Answer (score 5):

Those are not the same operations.  You are hoping that `e**119 + e**22` == `e**141`, but that's not how exponentiation works.  You can MAKE it the same, but it's a multiplicative operation, not an additive one:

```
sum_a = 1
for l in range(len(X)):
    sum_a *= np.exp(np.sum(W * X[l]))
sum_b = np.sum(np.exp(np.sum(W * X)))
```

And, by the way, the outer `np.sum` in that last line is useless.  The inner `np.sum` returns a single value.

***FOLLOWUP***

Ah, so you WANT the summation version.  You can do that by only summing over one axis:

```
sum_b = np.sum(np.exp(np.sum(W * X, axis=1)))
```

In this particular case, it's silly, because `e**119` is so much larger than `e**22` that the latter doesn't contribute.

Comment: Nonono, I want to make a vectorized operation equivalent to sum_a, not the other way around. I.e., I want to find a non-iterative approach in numpy that does sum_l^n(exp(sum_i^n(W[i] * X[l][i])))

Comment: Actually, @MichaelSzczesny, he said what he wanted, but we both interpreted it the other way around.